# No USB Security Key option in Chrome on Android

Tags: fido, passkey

with the [latest Chrome release which supports passkey](https://blog.chromium.org/2022/12/introducing-passkeys-in-chrome.html), I am not able to see the "USB Security key" option in Chrome on Android. I am not able to use a hardware authenticator such as Yubikey to register. The only option is Google Passkey.
[No USB Security Key option in Chrome on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC5Zy.jpg)

However, I can see the USB Security Key option in desktop environment (such as MacOS).

Please help to clarify what is the consideration or reason behind of not allowing USB Security key on Android mobile devices.

I want to use FIDO2 USB security key (such as Yubikey 5) to create Discoverable Credentials (Resident keys) in Chrome on Android.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use FIDO2 USB security key (such as Yubikey 5) to create Discoverable Credentials (Resident keys) in Chrome on Android.

Android does not yet support CTAP2, which is required in order to create discoverable credentials on security keys.